# How do I determine my vm's public URL? (IIS)

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008

A VM (virtual machine) has been provided for me to develop against (IIS) that is running Windows Server 2008.  How can I determine the VM's publicly-facing URL?  (that my users can hit with their web browser)

I am able to remote in to the VM via Remote Desktop.  Also, this is an existing VM that has been around for some time (I am just new to using it).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx

Essentially, you have to bind an IP (and/or port) for your IIS website. It's fairly straightforward.

Comment: I think all of the configuration stuff for the VM has already been done.  The VM has been established for some time, I am just new to it and don't know the public url.

Comment: You would be able to look at the active bindings through IIS as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, there are two methods:

1) on the command line ping with "-a" like this: "ping -a 123.45.678.90"

2) on the command line run "ipconfig /all" and put the Host Name in front of the Primary DNS suffix.